# Two scenes sharing a different scene wont segue

Tags: swift, ios8, storyboard, interface-builder, scene

So I have two different scenes in my storyboard and they both have a tableview cell that segues to a date picker scene. The first scene I built a segue from to the date picker scene works and also has an unwind segue.

The second scene's segue wont fire when trying to segue to the same date picker scene. It also has an unwind segue. I dont want to have to recreate scenes just to use them for different segues. Any way around this? I am very new to ios and swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I got around this was to use two Done buttons on the date picker scene because one button cant have two unwind methods. So when i segue from one scene to date picker scene I send a boolean in prepare for segue. In date picker scene I set the done button.hidden to that boolean.

Essentially just hiding and unhiding the correct button so i can unwind to the correct segue.